# Install request library with anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda

I tried to use sudo pip install requests but the terminal keeps stating that:

```
(base) OSX-MacBook-Pro:~ osx$ sudo pip install requests
WARNING: The directory '/Users/osx/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/osx/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (2019.9.11)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (1.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (2.8)
```

P/s: I have installed the Anaconda previously and already removed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- To install libraries in an Anaconda environment, you should do 
  `conda install <library_name>`
- To install the **requests** library, it would be `conda install requests`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`conda install requests`

If you already have requests installed then perhaps your python interpreter is looking in the wrong directory for your packages